# inheritance for spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, deserialization, spring-cloud-gcp

I am trying to implement a save and read operation to google firestore using spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore, but the POJO has a property that uses inheritance and of course can be several type. When i try to read the document, the library throws exception about:

**"No properties to serialize found on class <super_class>"**

There is any way that i can that works, maybe a way to implement a custom serializer|deserializer for spring-cloud-gcp-data-firestore.